# AND/OR not working in if/else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm having issues with AND/OR in an if/else PHP statement. This is one of the codes in particular:

```
if(is_page_template('page-home.php') || ('zaadvokati.php')) {
$class_trans = 'class="trans-color standard-menu"';
}else{
$class_trans = 'class="not-page-home standard-menu"';
}
```

If it's like this - with || / OR , it loads every паге template with the first class_trans option and not just the 2 templates specified, and if you put AND instead of OR, then it loads just the first one ('page-home.php') with the first class_trans and doesn't load the second one ('zaadvokati.php') with it. I suppose that, for some reason, it doesn't recognize the second template, but I don't know why.

Can you help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reiterate the function in the condition. try this:

```
if(is_page_template('page-home.php') || is_page_template('zaadvokati.php')) {
   $class_trans = 'class="trans-color standard-menu"';
}else{
   $class_trans = 'class="not-page-home standard-menu"';
}
```